# "Are gone" or "be gone" in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction

Are both alternatives correct in this sentence?

Let's enjoy the party now. Later, when all the guests **are gone**, we can talk about this.

Let's enjoy the party now. Later, when all the guests **be gone**, we can talk about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, **be gone** is not grammatically correct. I believe it is used in some dialects, but in normal English **be gone!** is only used as the imperative, meaning "go away".
... when all the guests **are gone** ... works OK, but probably most native speakers would say ... when all the guests **have gone** ...
Note that guests is plural and the verb must match.

Comment: _When all the guests be gone_ would be correct in older stages of English; you might well find it in Shakespeare, for example. Subordinators like _if_ and _when_ were previously followed by the subjunctive mood when introducing [irrealis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrealis_mood) clauses. It’s still just about possible, in very archaising, high registers to do this with _if_ (perhaps influenced by the famous quote, “If music _be_ the food of love, play on”), but doing it with _when_ would only work if you’re deliberately trying to sound like someone from the 18th century.

Comment: I wouldn’t go as far as to call it completely ungrammatical, but it is definitely _very, very_ marked and should be avoided in nearly all circumstances. (And of course the simple collocation _be gone_ is used outside of the imperative as well, anywhere an infinitive form is required; e.g., “She finds it hard to be gone so much of the time”, or “You need to be gone by the time I get back”.)

Comment: "Be gone!" as a simple imperative is correct, but very unusual. "Begone!" is the usual form for that meaning.

Answer (score 0):

### "Are gone" or "*will* be gone" are both acceptable.

"Later, when the guests are gone," describes a conditional: if the guests are gone in the future, we can talk.

"Later, when the guests will be gone," describes a conditional: the guests will be gone in the future, we can talk then.

It's a subtle difference, and not one that matters for this purpose. Either is fine.

"When the guests be gone" is nonsense. There are some archaic modes which use that construction; do not try to use them. Even if you get the use right (unlikely), it will still look wrong to modern readers/listeners.

Comment: Unless it's talk like a pirate day.